# how to know if an actor exists in an actor system or not

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

hi i want to create an actor in an actor system if its already not created here is my code

```
val sel = actorSystem.actorSelection("akka://ActorSystem/user/ReadOnlyAdminIndexMongoActor");
val asker = new AskableActorSelection(sel);

val future = asker.ask( Identify(1),Timeout(30 seconds))
val identity=Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[ActorIdentity]         

val reference = identity.getRef
if(reference != null){
     log.info("actor does not exists")
   }
   else
   {
     log.info("actor exists"+sel.toString())
   }
```

but this code is throwing exception

```
17:00:19.547 1822010 [ArteciateActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] EmptyLocalActorRef INFO - Message [scala.Tuple2] from Actor[akka://ActorSystem/temp/$e] to Actor[akka://ActorSystem/user/ReadOnlyAdminIndexMongoActor] was not delivered. [5] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
    at models.Global$.checkActor(Global.scala:71)
```

this is the code on line 71

```
val identity=Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[ActorIdentity]
```

please help me where i am mistaken and also i am using this code from this  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331950/three-ways-to-know-existence-of-an-akka-actor) and this [Link the code givein in an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012945/how-can-i-check-if-an-akka-actor-exists-akka-2-2)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Identify` is the proper way to determine if an actor exists. Receiving an ask timeout is *generally* an indicator that it does not, since there was no actor there to respond. I say *generally* because message traffic load and/or remoting could result in a timeout for other reasons.

My question is, since you have a well known address, under what circumstances could this actor not exist? Do you just want to create it lazily on demand, or are you trying to recover from a crash of the the actor?

For both scenarios, I would suggest a proxy pattern, i.e. have a simple, crash-proof (due to its simplicity) actor live at the well known address, which is responsible for creating the `ReadOnlyAdminIndexMongoActor` on demand and proxying messages to it. This proxy would also be the supervisor, recovering the actor on crash. It even allows you to idle timeout the `ReadOnlyAdminIndexMongoActor` if it makes sense, since everyone will always talk to it via the proxy.

A simplistic implementation of this proxy (without supervisor or idle timeout handling) might look like:

```
class OnDemandProxyActor(proxyProps: Props) extends Actor {

  def receive = waiting()

  def waiting: Receive = {
    case msg =>
       val target = context.actorOf(proxyProps)
       target forward msg
       context.become(proxying(target))
  }

  def proxying(target: ActorRef): Receive = {
    case msg => target forward msg
  }
}
```

where `proxyProps` are the `Props` for creating your actor on demand, `waiting` is the initial state where no message has been received and hence the proxy `target` has not yet been created and `proxying` is the state after the `target` is created. Both states use `forward` to send the received message to the `target` as if it had come from the original `sender`.

Comment: yes i want to create it on demand can you please give an code example of it of proxy pattern?

Comment: Let me know if the above example explains it