# akka.net managing actor hiearchy and creating/getting actors

Tags: akka, akka.net

I am learning akka and am not sure how best to organize, get/create my actors.

Right now I have a setup like

```
Department (1000s) can each have many items (10000s) and each item has properties and work that can be done to it
```

If I want to perform a task on Item C which is in Department 3 what is the best way to accomplish this?

I have currently set everything up so that I would have to tell Department 3 a message then in Department 3 actor I would tell the Item C actor the same message.

The problem I see with this is anytime I want to tell the Item something I have to handle the message in 2 places (Department and Item).  This feels wrong to me but maybe that is because I don't understand the pattern.

I am also wanting this to be stateful so I want the actors to persist.  That creates another challenge for me.  How do I know if Department 3 is loaded (And once I have Department 3 how do I know if there is an Actor for Item B that is initialized)?  I could just use the Selection method on the Context but then I have to check its identity to determine if it is really there.  What I have done is maintain a list of loaded Departments then check to see if my department is in that list then get the department or create it.

With this process I introduced another actor that manages the list of all my departments.  Now all messages that I want to send to my Item B actor has to go through the Actor that manages all departments, Department 3 Actor, then finally to Item B actor.  This now feels even worse than before.

Now I also have Department Supervisor that knows all the Departments that are loaded that all messages must go through (Department destination messages and Item Destination messages).  At this point all messages flow through this single actor which I worry about performance and maintainability now.

So my question is: Is there a better way to have this parent / child relationships while remaining stateful and to be able to send a message to an Item without knowing if the Department it is in is loaded or if it is loaded itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331950/three-ways-to-know-existence-of-an-akka-actor) regarding checking if an Actor exists. One strategy is to create all your Department actors using a supervisor and use this to manage failures as discussed [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fault-tolerance.html). Your supervisor would know which Actors have already been created and will be notified upon failure, so you can handle it here.

Do you need to split the actors into Items? They sound more like message types to me. Could you not just model the Departments and then send them Item messages? Alternatively, could you have DepartmentItem Actors? (i.e. don't have department Actors, just model the Items?). If you do need to model Items as Actors then I think what you have is the right path - supervisors with children is the way to go. You can always forward the messages if it helps:

```
target.Forward(result, Context);
```